# Wedding Invitation

Tags: word-choice

I have searched in internet for english/american wedding's invitation text. I have prepared something, but I would like to check it with some native speakers, before printing. Could you please have a look on it?

Together with their families

Joanna and Jacek

would love to invite

Ben and Sara

to their wedding

On July 24th 2021

at three o'clock in the afternoon

in Saint John Church in CRACOW

Join us in celebration at the reception immediately following the ceremony

Pod Kogutkiem, Mickiewicza St 7,

32-442 Krzywaczka, Poland

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations!  Basically that is fine.  Wedding invitations used to be very formal but providing it has all the necessary information any form that you feel is appropriate is acceptable - it's your wedding!

Slight changes:

- 'On July ...' -> 'on July ...' (lower case 'o')
- 'at three o'clock in the afternoon' - ok, or just 'at 3pm'
- 'in Saint John Church in CRACOW' -> 'at St John's Church in Cracow.' or 'at the Church of St John in Cracow.'  Is that the full name of the church? Might be worth adding the address if there is any possibility of confusion about which church you mean.
- 'Join us in celebration ...' -> 'Please join us in celebration ...' (it's a request)

You probably want to add RSVP details and a date

- "Please reply by July 1 by email to xx@example.com" or whatever.

Comment: Thank you so much!